# Django QuerySet update_or_create creating duplicate entries

Tags: django, django-queryset

Recently I'm facing issues in [update_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create) method. Let me give a full explanation first.

**Model:**

```
class TransactionPageVisits(models.Model):
    transactionid = models.ForeignKey(
        Transaction,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        db_column='transactionid',
    )
    sessionid = models.CharField(max_length=40, db_index=True)
    ip_address = models.CharField(max_length=39, editable=False)
    user_agent = models.TextField(null=True, editable=False)
    page = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, db_index=True)
    method = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    url = models.TextField(null=False, editable=False)
    created_dtm = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta(object):
        ordering = ('created_dtm',)
```

**Function:**

```
def _tracking(self, request, response, **kwargs):
    txn_details = kwargs.get('txn_details')
    data = {
        'sessionid': request.session.session_key,
        'ip_address': get_ip_address(request),
        'user_agent': get_user_agent(request),
        'method': request.method,
        'url': request.build_absolute_uri(),
        'transactionid': txn_details.txn_object,
        'page': kwargs.get('page')
    }

    # Keep updating/creating tracking data to model
    obj, created = TransactionPageVisits.objects.update_or_create(**data)
```

**Notes:**

I know I'm not passing any **defaults** arguments to update_or_create(), as at the time the code was written it was not required (wanted to create a new row only when all the columns as per **data** is collectively unique).
Also _tracking() is in middleware and will be called in each request and response.

Everything was going smoothly until today I got following exception:

```
File "trackit.py", line 65, in _tracking
    obj, created = TransactionPageVisits.objects.update_or_create(**data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.10.4-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.10.4-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/query.py", line 488, in update_or_create
    obj = self.get(**lookup)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.10.4-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/query.py", line 389, in get
    (self.model._meta.object_name, num)
MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one TransactionPageVisits -- it returned 2!
```

I noticed that there were two entries created in the table with exactly same value (except created_dtm as it was having auto_add_now=True):

```
| id    | sessionid                        | ip_address     | user_agent                                                                     | page | method | url                                                                                                    | created_dtm                | transactionid |
| 32858 | nrq2vwxbtsjp8yoibotpsur0zit5jhoq | xx.xxx.xxx.xxx | Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:58.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0 |      | GET    | https://www.example.com/example_url/?jobid=5a9f2acb4cedfd00011c7d5d&transactionid=XXXXXXXXXXXX | 2018-03-06 23:57:00.061280 | XXXXXXXXXXXX  |
| 32859 | nrq2vwxbtsjp8yoibotpsur0zit5jhoq | xx.xxx.xxx.xxx | Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:58.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0 |      | GET    | https://www.example.com/example_url/?jobid=5a9f2acb4cedfd00011c7d5d&transactionid=XXXXXXXXXXXX | 2018-03-06 23:57:00.062121 | XXXXXXXXXXXX  |
```

**Why at the first place a duplicate entry created in the table?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`update_or_create` is prone to a race condition, as described in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create):

> As described above in get_or_create(), this method is prone to a
>   race-condition which can result in multiple rows being inserted
>   simultaneously if uniqueness is not enforced at the database level.

You can use `unique_together` in the model, as suggested in another answer. I've never tested this, but apparently [Django catches the `IntegrityError` caused by these race conditions](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24009#comment:3).

Comment: IMO this quote from the docs is wrong since Django 1.11 that fixes the underlying race condition. I'm asking for confirmation on IRC. However this is still relevant for Django 1.10 which is the (deprecated) version used by the OP, and in the case the db engine does not support transactions.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right, there is a [commit](https://github.com/django/django/commit/d44afd889275473c97474cca19467d1509e0fcc1) with the fix.

Comment: @AntoinePinsard Actually, I think a race condition can always exist. `select_for_update` locks the row, *if it exists*. But if two different threads try a `get` and the object doesn't exist, they will both create it (the whole table isn't locked). The fix just prevents concurrent updates to an object that already exists.

Comment: Indeed, you're right again. This lowers the risk of race condition but it still exists. That's what I've been told on IRC too.

Comment: @PauloAlmeida: Thanks for pointing the commit. It fixes the issue in **django 1.11**, nice implementation of locking using `transaction.atomic()`. Lol have to check with my manager whether we can upgrade django or just add a try-except as of now! :D

Comment: @SauravKumar No problem. I think you realize this, but just to be clear, you do need to enforce the uniqueness at the database level, with `unique_together`, even if you upgrade.

Answer (score 3):

I am not able to fully diagnose this issue because without the defaults, it still does have the chance to act unexpectedly (in my opinion). I would suggest, however, potentially looking into the [unique_together](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/options/#unique-together) to enforce the uniqueness within the database, which can force the uniqueness of the fields in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The source code goes on to find the unique element with the given parameters.

```
def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Perform the query and return a single object matching the given
    keyword arguments.
    """
    clone = self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
    if self.query.can_filter() and not self.query.distinct_fields:
        clone = clone.order_by()
    num = len(clone)
    if num == 1:
        return clone._result_cache[0]
    if not num:
        raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
            "%s matching query does not exist." %
            self.model._meta.object_name
        )
    raise self.model.MultipleObjectsReturned(
        "get() returned more than one %s -- it returned %s!" %
        (self.model._meta.object_name, num)
    )
```

The parameters that you have given certainly are similar to two objects.

```
data = {
    'sessionid': request.session.session_key,
    'ip_address': get_ip_address(request),
    'user_agent': get_user_agent(request),
    'method': request.method,
    'url': request.build_absolute_uri(),
    'transactionid': txn_details.txn_object,
    'page': kwargs.get('page')
}
```

Do you want to update both of them? Do you want to keep the entries unique?

Comment: I saw get() function and figured already that it was due to multiple objects.. But my question was **Why at the first place itself multiple rows created?** This line of code will simply ignore and won't do anything if there's already an existing entry for collectively all fields: `obj, created = TransactionPageVisits.objects.update_or_create(**data)`