# Duplicate data after using update_or_create

Tags: python, django

In my project I retrieve data from an API that I save on my database created in parallel, the problem is that the initial data is duplicated each time I refresh the page that executes the API

models.py

```
class Empl(models.Model):
    code=models.CharField(max_length=10,blank=True,null=True)
    age=models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
    service=models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
```

views.py

```
url='http://myAPI/Empl/GetEmpl'
x=requests.get(url)
content=x.json()
for data in content:
    emp , _ = Empl.objects.update_or_create(code=data['code'],age=data['age'],service=data['service'])
    emp.save()
```

At the level of my project when I look for an employee on the search bar, several employees with the same data. And this every time I refresh the page that executes the API, the initial data is duplicated and so on.
Oddly when I perform a filter on an employee through her code in Mysql Base I get a single tuple, I don't understand?

Comment: The issue probably comes from a race condition : https://stackoverflow.com/a/49152852/270209 you should enforce integrity on db level.
Also, why are you using `update_or_create` if you don't do updates (i.e the `defaults=` part). Also the save() is unnecessary there. Don't you want to use `get_or_create` instead?

Comment: None of code, service  are unique...So I guess it will create new object every time. Make cod unique( if possible) might update the record if try to save again...or need to change schema

Comment: But here how I will manage the fact that two employees have the same name, the same age and different service. How to apply this on the model ???